# Implementing A* Search...but as a graph walk

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star, maze

Trying to implement A* search in Java, except I can only see the neighboring nodes of my current location, which means I can't iterate over the neighbors of any stored node, only the node I'm standing on.

I have a pretty concrete implementation down already, with one MAJOR problem...

```
    final Map<Long, AStarPrimeNode> nodesData= new HashMap<>();
    final FibonacciHeap<AStarPrimeNode> openList= new FibonacciHeap<>();
    final Map<AStarPrimeNode, FibonacciHeap.Entry<AStarPrimeNode>> entries= new HashMap<>();
    AStarPrimeNode startNodeData= new AStarPrimeNode(s.currentLocation(), s.distanceToRing());
    startNodeData.setG(0);
    int f= startNodeData.getF();
    nodesData.put(s.currentLocation(), startNodeData);
    entries.put(startNodeData, openList.enqueue(startNodeData, f));

    final Map<Long, Long> resPath= new HashMap<>();
    final Set<AStarPrimeNode> closedList= new HashSet<>();

    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
        final AStarPrimeNode data= openList.dequeueMin().getValue();
        if (data.getH() == 0) { return buildPath(resPath); }

        closedList.add(data);

        for (NodeStatus neighbor : data.neighbors()) { 
            AStarPrimeNode neighborData;
            if (nodesData.containsKey(neighbor.getId()))
                neighborData= nodesData.get(neighbor.getId());
            else {
                neighborData= new AStarPrimeNode(neighbor);
                nodesData.put(neighborData.getID(), neighborData);
            }

            if (closedList.contains(neighborData)) continue;

            int newG= data.getG() + 1;

            if (newG < neighborData.getG()) {
                neighborData.setG(newG);
                f= neighborData.getF();

                resPath.put(neighborData.getID(), data.getID());
                if (!entries.containsKey(neighborData))
                    entries.put(neighborData, openList.enqueue(neighborData, f));
                else openList.decreaseKey(entries.get(neighborData), f);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
```

the call `data.neighbors()` is impossible. I cannot retrieve the neighbors of `data`. The only neighbors I can retrieve are the ones of my current position, stored in the game state s.

What to do?

Comment: It looks like you've implemented A* search, but the algorithm you're trying to implement doesn't sound like it's A* search at all. Are you just trying to write a greedy, best-first-search function that uses a heuristic to guide the next move? It doesn't sound to me like there is any backtracking in your algorithm, so no need for a queue or guarantee that you're going to explore the most optimal path at every step: just the best one available from the current node, walking straight forward along only one path. That's not really A*, is it?

Comment: @inordirection you might be right! in that case how would I go about implementing that? that almost sounds like it would be closer to a depth first search with conditions.

Comment: Yeah, A* but only using information from the current node would be like DFS where you choose the best option according to your heuristic rather than recursing deeper in arbitrary order. However, with this approach by itself I think it would be possible that you could potentially get into a cycle if you end up walking into a dead-end and you can't keep a visited set or backtrack easily to the last un-explored path like you do in regular DFS.

Comment: I looked at your other post... If you can't store any information about the path you've traveled or the nodes you've explored so far, like if the robot walking this maze has no internal state and can only look at it's current position and neighbors positions and apply manhattan heuristic but it has no memory at all, then I don't really see how you do better than a random walk with a slight bias introduced towards minimizing the heuristic. I'm not saying for sure that you can't do better than that, but I don't see how.

Comment: What is the problem with getting the neighbors from `s` ? Alternatively modify the node to hold the list of neighbors. For more help post [MRE]